# How do I apply JavaScript functions to selection forms?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having issues with figuring out how to apply JavaScript functionality to HTML. I thought that it was very simple, but for some reason my code isn't working.

Below is the HTML portion of the code. It includes an input, two dropdown menus (to select different currency types), a button, and a section to output the answer. I've removed most of the code just to make it easier to read, and because it's all essentially the same repeated.

```
<input type="number" id="money" placeholder="Enter starting cash" />
<select id="incur">
      <option value = "1">USD</option>
</select>
<select id="outcur">
      <option value = "2">CAD</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="start">Submit</button>
<p id="result" style="font-size:20pt; color:#E00;"></p>
```

The HTML appears fine on the page, but it has no functionality. Clicking *submit* doesn't do anything, and I never see the result paragraph tag.

Here's a portion of the JavaScript. The rest of it is, again, pretty much the same thing but copied and pasted and with modified values.

Here is the input portion:

```
    document.getElementById("start").onclick = function () {
        'use strict';

        var incur = document.getElementById("incur");
        incur = incur.options[incur.selectedIndex].value;

        var outcur = document.getElementById("outcur");
        outcur = outcur.options[outcur.selectedIndex].value;

        var m = document.getElementById("money").value;


        /* USD */
        if (incur == 1) {
            var i = "USD";
            if (outcur == 2){
                report(m, i, (m * 1.35).toFixed(2), "CAD");
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is the output portion:

```
    var report = function (inmoney, intype, outmoney, outtype) {
        'use strict';
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
            inmoney + " " + intype + " = " + outmoney + " " + outtype;
    };
```

Why is my code not doing anything? I can't seem to find anything wrong with it, unless I don't understand how to use document.getElementById

The code should work like this:

1. Input a numerical value in the input form, say 10
2. Select a value for the input and output (only options here are USD and CAD)
3. Press "Submit"
4. JavaScript calculates that 10 USD = 13.23 CAD and outputs that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the declaration of your `report` function variable to before its usage:

```js
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function() {
  'use strict';

  var incur = document.getElementById("incur");
  incur = incur.options[incur.selectedIndex].value;

  var outcur = document.getElementById("outcur");
  outcur = outcur.options[outcur.selectedIndex].value;

  var m = document.getElementById("money").value;

  var report = function(inmoney, intype, outmoney, outtype) {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
      inmoney + " " + intype + " = " + outmoney + " " + outtype;
  };

  /* USD */
  if (incur == 1) {
    var i = "USD";
    if (outcur == 2) {
      report(m, i, (m * 1.35).toFixed(2), "CAD");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="money" placeholder="Enter starting cash" />
<select id="incur">
      <option value = "1">USD</option>
</select>
<select id="outcur">
      <option value = "2">CAD</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="start">Submit</button>
<p id="result" style="font-size:20pt; color:#E00;"></p>
```

Take a look at [function declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting) for the underlying reasons.

Comment: I provide an executable snippet in my answer that demonstrably does work. If it's not working for you, there's an issue in some code that you have not provided in your question.